# Key not in dictionary producing KeyError 1

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting `KeyError 1` and unsure why it reproduces this error.

```
for i in range(num_clusters):
    if i != 0:
        words ="Cluster %d words: " % i
        print (words)

    for j, ind in enumerate(order_centroids[i, :10]):
        if (j == 0):
            words1= '%s' % vocab_df.loc[terms[ind].split(' ')].values.tolist()[0][0]
            print (words1)
        else:
           words2= '%s' % vocab_df.loc[terms[ind].split(' ')].values.tolist()[0][0]
           print (words2)

    titles="Cluster %d titles: " % i
    print (titles)
    for j, title in enumerate(df.loc[i]['title'].values.tolist()):
        if (j == 0):
            title1= '%s' % title
            print(title1)
        else:
            title2= ', %s' % title
            print (title2)
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py" in get_loc 2897.
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx" in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc 107.
    <source code not available>
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx" in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc 131.
    <source code not available>
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi" in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item 992.
    <source code not available>
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi" in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item 998.
    <source code not available>

During handling of the above exception (1), another exception occurred:
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner 34.
    response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response 115.
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response 113.
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\waqaf\waqaf\views.py" in output4 638.
    for j, title in enumerate(df.loc[i]['title'].values.tolist()):
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py" in __getitem__ 1424.
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py" in _getitem_axis 1850.
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py" in _get_label 160.
    return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py" in xs 3735.
    loc, new_index = self.index.get_loc_level(key, drop_level=drop_level)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py" in get_loc_level 2856.
    indexer = self._get_level_indexer(key, level=level)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py" in _get_level_indexer 2939.
    code = level_index.get_loc(key)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py" in get_loc 2899.
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx" in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc 107.
    <source code not available>
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx" in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc 131.
    <source code not available>
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi" in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item 992.
    <source code not available>
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi" in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item 998.
    <source code not available>
  Exception Type: KeyError at /output4
  Exception Value: 1
```

The output that I wanted is:

```
Clusters:
----------------------------------------
Cluster 0 words: mathematics, accounting, engineering, understanding, finance, book, business, edition, basic, courses
Cluster 0 titles: Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications.txt, financial accounting.txt, First Engineering mathematics.txt, Foundations of Finance.txt, Linear Algebra.txt, quantitative business analysis for uitm.txt
Cluster 1 words: programming, c++, computer, c++, language, book, science, extensibility, software, computer
Cluster 1 titles: a gift of fire.txt, C++ for Dummies.txt, C++ How To Program.txt, Introduction to C++ Programming.txt
Cluster 2 words: web, applications, internet, simple, book, databases, programming, applications, building, techniques
Cluster 2 titles: Internet & World Wide Web .txt, PHP & MYSQL for Dummies.txt
```

Can anyone please explain why this is happening? I looked for a solution and still couldn't figure out how to solve this problem. it seems like I can't access to the key of the dictionary which is title (not sure if this is right).

Example of data: `biochemistry.txt`

`- welcome to the study of the chemistry of life. as you venture into this exiting and dynamic discipline, you'll discover many new and wonderful things. you'll learn how some enzymes can catalyze chemical reactions at speeds close to theoretical limits- reactions that would otherwise occur only at imperceptibly low rates. you'll learn about the forces that maintain biomolecular structure and how even some of the weakest of those forces make life possible. you'll also learn how biochemistry has thousands of applications in day-to-day lide- in medicine, drug design, nutrition, forensic science, agriculture, and manufacturing. in short, you'll begin a journey of discovery about how chemistry makes life both possible and better.`

Comment: Can you provide a toy dataset?

Comment: I saved my data in a text file, where the title of the book is the name of the text file and a description of the book is saved in the text file. eg: biochemistry.txt and the data inside the text file would be text that will describe the file name

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please check tips on how to ask questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The error traceback doesn’t seem to mention a KeyError, am I missing something? Also, why are you always converting the columns to NumPy arrays and then to lists? Do you have a [mcve]? A lot of this code looks a bit bizarre, I’m curious as to what your DataFrame looks like.

Comment: your error stems from this line: `for j, title in enumerate(df.loc[i]['title'].values.tolist()):` Try changing `.loc` for `.iloc`.

Comment: I changed loc to iloc and I got another error:
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['

Comment: @ntsha That’s bizarre, where did you get that error? I think you can actually (and should) use `.loc[]`, just include the column name you have right after inside the loc.

Comment: when I use .loc[] it produces keyerror 1 and when I used .iloc[] I gives invalid literal for int() with base 10:[
I really have no clue on how to fix this error

Comment: `[` can means that you convert some list to string and now it can't get char `[` from string like `[1,2,3]`. Why do you use `'%s' % ....`? It convert results to string which may be useless if you need to work with list of data. You don't need it to `print()` it.

Comment: when i remove %s it still produces the same error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[' 
 I put print() to display the data on a web browser

Comment: still gives me same error I'm doing something wrong if you can help me with it will be really thank full